# Chef 12 -> Chef 13 include_recipe changes

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

We have a cookbook with multiple recipes where we select features.  In this case, it's Couchbase and we want to be able to have `data`, `query`, and `index` nodes tagged in Datadog, but that's probably more than you need to know...  Anyhow, one or more features can be selected.

So, we have 3 recipes, one for each concern.  Each recipe adds the feature name to an array and then `include_recipe cookbook::default`

With Chef 12, we could select multiple feature recipes and then it seemed to wait until all of them were processed to run the default cookbook, so it could aggregate the array and process all the chosen features together.

With Chef 13, it appears to be run immediately after the first feature recipe is processed, so that subsequent `include_recipe` are skipped.

As a workaround, of course, I've changed some of the logic, but finding details on this behavior change hasn't come up with anything.

Thanks for any help...

-H

Answer (score 0):

Rubber Duck.  Turns out because we changed `.set` to `.default`, we lost the ability to have the variables properly set during the first run.  `.normal` will do it for us.